# Perl Inserting a string from a file after every occurence of a slash in a url

Tags: string, perl, permutation

I have the following URL's:

**FILE1.txt**

```
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
192.168.192.168/lion/tiger/elephant/
```

**FILE2.txt**

```
HELLO
GOODBYE
```

**The output I am trying to achieve:**

```
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/catHELLO/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/cat/rabbitHELLO/hamster/
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/hamsterHELLO/
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/HELLO

http://www.stackoveflow.com/dogGOODBYE/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/catGOODBYE/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/cat/rabbitGOODBYE/hamster/
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/hamsterGOODBYE/
http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/GOODBYE

192.168.192.168/lionHELLO/tiger/elephant/
192.168.192.168/lion/tigerHELLO/elephant/
192.168.192.168/lion/tiger/elephantHELLO/
192.168.192.168/lion/tiger/elephant/HELLO

192.168.192.168/lionGOODBYE/tiger/elephant/
192.168.192.168/lion/tigerGOODBYE/elephant/
192.168.192.168/lion/tiger/elephantGOODBYE/
192.168.192.168/lion/tiger/elephant/GOODBYE
```

As you can see the strings `HELLO` and `GOODBYE` are inserted after every slash, and if there is already a string after the slash it will append the `HELLO` and `GOODBYE` after that (e.g `http://www.stackoveflow.com/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/hamster/` and so on).

**What I have tried**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @f1 = do {
   open my $fh, '<', 'FILE1.txt';
   <$fh>;
};
chomp @f1;

my @f2 = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'FILE2.txt';
  <$fh>;
};
chomp @f2;

for my $f1 (@f1) {
  my @fields = $f1 =~ m{[^/]+}g;
  for my $f2 (@f2) {
    for my $i (0 .. $#fields) {
      my @new = @fields;
      $new[$i] .= $f2;
      print qq{/$_/\n}, for join '/', @new;
    }
    print "\n\n";
  }
}
#courtesy of Borodin
```

**However** this code does not cater for url's that have the slashes in the `http://` part as these are replaced with `http:HELLO/` when it should not do.

Also it does not put `HELLO` or `GOODBYE` after the slash if there is no string already there e.g `http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/<--SHOULD PUT HELLO AFTER THIS SLASH AS WELL BUT DOSN'T`

It appears that this code removes then re-inserts the slashes with the strings from FILE2.txt, as opposed to inserting `HELLO` and `GOODBYE` in the correct place to start with.

**My question**

**Is there a better method of going about achieving the output I require or is there something I can do to my existing code to cater for the problems described above?**

Your help is much appreciated, many thanks

Comment: Can you show *any* of the ways you tried?

Comment: Are the strings in `FILE1.txt` file paths, or are they just strings that happens to use slash as a separator?

Comment: @Wooble - Explained and described my question better, hopefully good enough to reopen? thanks

Comment: So they weren't file paths and now they are? And you didn't want anything after the final slash but now you do? And now the whole string has `http:/` at the start that you want to leave untouched? You still have made no attempt to solve this problem yourself, but have just copied my solution (minus the essential `use autodie`) and asked for further enhancement. *This is not polite behaviour*, and certainly doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. Make some effort yourself and come back here when you have hit a *specific* problem.

Comment: @Borodin - Can I just explain please, I do understand where your coming from. My original question was highly simplified for the purposes of explaining my question, which is why I originally did not include the http:/ and final slash parts, because I thought that by knowing this I would be able to change my code to accommodate the http:/ and final slash by myself. However your code and way of doing it was far better than the way I was trying doing it so decided to use your method instead, which is where I have now become stuck trying to make the http:/ and final slash changes, see next comment

Comment: @Borodin - Also the reason I have copied your code into my question is because the question got closed and would not be reopened until I better explained it with some example code, which is why I used your code from your answer as this was the method I now wanted to use, i was not in any way trying to pass it off as my own code or be inpolite, but I can see why it would be perceived this way. I apologise for doing that but it was done with the best intentions and am genuinely grateful for your help, thank you very much.

Comment: You have changed the question so that my code is no longer relevant. You should post your *real problem* and your *own code*, and describe where you cannot progress. Put that in a new question and you may get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than splitting the line on every slash, you can do it all with a regex.

Updated version:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @insert_words = qw/HELLO GOODBYE/;
my $word = 0;

while (<DATA>)
{
    chomp;
    foreach my $word (@insert_words)
    {
        my $repeat = 1;
        while ((my $match=$_) =~ s|(?<!/)(?:/(?!/)[^/]*){$repeat}[^/]*\K|$word|)
        {
            print "$match\n";
            $repeat++;
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
```

The key is the substitution operator: `s|(?<!/)(?:/(?!/)[^/]*){$repeat}[^/]*\K|$word|`.

`(?<!/)` and `(?!/)` are negative look-behind and look-ahead, respectively.  They ensure that we are only matching a single `/`, thus ignoring `http://`.

`(?:/(?!/)[^/]*){$repeat}` is a capturing group that must match a specified number of times, and we increase that number until it no longer matches.

I had to use `[^/]*` instead of `[^/]+` to meet your requirement of matching at the end of the string.  That is why both the look-behind and the look-ahead are needed.

`\K` means "match everything up to this point, but don't include it in the match itself." Thus we don't have to worry about including the whole beginning of the string that matched in the replacement.

**Note:** The `r` option is another way to perform substitution without modifying the original string.  However, it requires Perl 5.16 (thanks Amon).  Thus I removed it from the example.

Comment: @dan1111 The `/r` option is quite new (v16, I think). This may cause some problems. The traditional idiom is `(my $copy = $original) =~ s/foo//`

Comment: @amon, I came across that option recently but didn't realize it was new. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @dan1111 - This is the error I get when trying to run it. I get the same error on two different systems. `Bareword found where operator expected at stringTest.pl line 13, near "s|(?:/\w+){$repeat}\w+\K|$word|r"
syntax error at stringTest.pl line 13, near "s|(?:/\w+){$repeat}\w+\K|$word|r"
Global symbol "$match" requires explicit package name at stringTest.pl line 15.
syntax error at stringTest.pl line 20, near "}"
Execution of stringTest.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`, thanks

Comment: @dan - If this was to now accomodate URLS with the `http://` part what would need changing in the regular expression as all things I have tested currently return something similar to the following `http://wwwHELLO.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/`. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @perl-user, the problem there is that `\w+` only matches word characters: letters, numbers, and underscores.  You could use `[^/]+` instead in each place where `\w+` appears in the pattern.  This will match anything but a slash.

Comment: @dan1111 - Yes, thats what I was looking for thanks. Also I am trying to get it to accommodate all forms of possible urls i.e the `http://` and also urls that have the IP address at the start for example `10.11.12.13/dog/cat/`. However as I have increased `my $repeat = 2;` to prevent `http://www.bbc.co.ukHELLO/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/` from occuring it misses the first slash when it is an ip address url? any thoughts on what to change, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @dan1111 - thanks that helped a lot - I am now attempting to add to the regular expression so that it will do what it does currently for the slash, for any non- alphanumeric character that it comes across. For example `http://www.stackoveflow.com=dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/` should become `http://www.stackoveflow.com=dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/hamster/` and so on, but I keep getting strange output, any thoughts? thanks a lot

Comment: @perl-user, you could replace each `/` in the pattern with a character class of the characters you want to match.  Instead of `/` use `[/,=]` for example if you want to match `/`, `,`, and `=`.  Likewise the negative classes would have to be updated to `[^/,=]`.  However, you need to think carefully about what you want to match.    The urls contain non-alphanumeric characters like `:` and `.`.  If you want to match those it will mess up the exclusion of the URL portion.

Comment: @perl-user, the latest version I included corrects that problem of the end of the string.

Comment: @perl-user, it is because you didn't `chomp` each input line from the file to remove newlines.  This is something I also added to my example since the original.

Comment: @dan1111 - apologies for that, I had it commented out when i was testing, thank you very much, I have learnt a lot from your help.

Comment: @dan1111 - At the moment it appends `$word` to the string after the slash if there is one, what would be required to make this prefix it as well, for example `http://www.stackoveflow.com/dog/HELLOcat/rabbit/hamster/` and so on? - I don't require it do this at present, but it will help me understand the different aspects of the regex in more detail. thanks a lot

Comment: @perl-user, I suggest you try that yourself.  It would be a good learning exercise.

Comment: @dan1111 - I have become stuck again altering the the regular expression so that it will overwrite the string after the slash, as well as the functionality it already has, for example using `http://stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/` will become  `http://stackoverflow.com/dogHELLO/cat/` `http://stackoverflow.com/dog/catHELLO/` `http://stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLO` **then also do** `http://stackoverflow.com/HELLO/cat/` `http://stackoverflow.com/dog/HELLO/` `http://stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLO`. If you could offer any assistance I would be very grateful, thanks for your help

Comment: @perl-user, I believe your original question has been answered quite adequately (with quite a few additions and changes already).  If you have a new problem, please ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the algorithm in prose:

```
Open File2.txt. Read in all lines, removing the newline. We call the array @words.

Open File2.txt. We call the file handle $fh.

As long as we can read a $line from $fh:

    Remove the newline, remove starting and ending slashes.
    Split the $line at every slash, call the array @animals.

    Loop through the @words, calling each element $word:

        Loop through the indices of the @animals, calling each index $i:

            Make a @copy of the @animals.
            Append the $word to the $i-th element of @copy.
            Join the @copy with slashes, surround it with slashes, and print with newline.

        Print an empty line.
```

Answer (score 2):

This program will do what you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @f1 = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'FILE1.txt';
  <$fh>;
};
chomp @f1;

my @f2 = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'FILE2.txt';
  <$fh>;
};
chomp @f2;

for my $f1 (@f1) {
  my @fields = $f1 =~ m{[^/]+}g;
  for my $f2 (@f2) {
    for my $i (0 .. $#fields) {
      my @new = @fields;
      $new[$i] .= $f2;
      print qq{/$_/\n}, for join '/', @new;
    }
    print "\n\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/hamster/
/dog/catHELLO/rabbit/hamster/
/dog/cat/rabbitHELLO/hamster/
/dog/cat/rabbit/hamsterHELLO/


/dogGOODBYE/cat/rabbit/hamster/
/dog/catGOODBYE/rabbit/hamster/
/dog/cat/rabbitGOODBYE/hamster/
/dog/cat/rabbit/hamsterGOODBYE/


/lionHELLO/tiger/elephant/
/lion/tigerHELLO/elephant/
/lion/tiger/elephantHELLO/


/lionGOODBYE/tiger/elephant/
/lion/tigerGOODBYE/elephant/
/lion/tiger/elephantGOODBYE/
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking to achieve, thanks. If these were indeed now file paths or urls, e.g `http://stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/` - how would I go about getting it to not care about the slashes in the `http://` part?

Comment: Please see my edited question, had to edit it as it got closed, thanks for your help

Comment: I am genuinely stuck with trying to accomodate the http:// and adding it after the final slash as well, any further help with this would be highly appreciated, thanks a lot